# The cycle space and cut space are orthogonal complement

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following theorem:
Let $G$ be a graph. The cycle space and cut space are orthogonal complement if and only if the graph $G$ has an odd number of spanning tree.

My attempt:

I define the matrix $H=\left [
\begin{array}{c|c}
Q \\ B\end{array}
\right ]
$ where $Q$ and $B$ are cut matrix and circuit matrix respectively. I thought about $|H^tH|$.

Comment: See http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-96-14.pdf